# Compare current row with all previous rows and a condition to consider

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to compare my school_start date for same student with previous `school_start_date`. If `school_start` date are different for a given student it should check the `school_end_date`.  If the `school_end_date` (from previous rows) is same for the school_start_date of the student we are currently checking. 
 Then, I need to consider that first type_sub with respect to school_end_date or we can directly type_sub w.r.t to `school_start_date` (if `school_start_date` and current `school_start_date` are same)

I have tried to work using `PARTITION BY` clause but I am stuck.

**Table**

```
  student_subscriber | school_start | school_end | typeofsub 
 --------------------|--------------|------------|----------- 
                  22 | 12/7/2016    | 12/8/2016  |       111 
                  22 | 12/7/2016    | 12/12/2016 |       112 
                  22 | 12/7/2016    | 12/10/2016 |       112 
                  22 | 12/7/2016    | 12/20/2016 |       112 
                  22 | 12/8/2016    | 12/10/2016 |       112 
                  23 | 12/12/2016   | 12/13/2016 |       111 
                  23 | 12/12/2016   | 12/12/2016 |       112 
                  23 | 12/12/2016   | 12/14/2016 |       112 
                  23 | 12/12/2016   | 12/20/2016 |       112 
                  23 | 12/13/2016   | 12/20/2016 |       112
```

**Table_Output**

```
  student_subscriber | school_start | school_end | typeofsub | First_Typeofsub 
 --------------------|--------------|------------|-----------|----------------- 
                  22 | 12/7/2016    | 12/8/2016  |       111 |             111 
                  22 | 12/7/2016    | 12/12/2016 |       112 |             111 
                  22 | 12/7/2016    | 12/10/2016 |       112 |             111 
                  22 | 12/7/2016    | 12/20/2016 |       112 |             111 
                  22 | 12/8/2016    | 12/10/2016 |       112 |             111 
                  23 | 12/12/2016   | 12/13/2016 |       112 |             112 
                  23 | 12/12/2016   | 12/12/2016 |       113 |             112 
                  23 | 12/12/2016   | 12/14/2016 |       113 |             112 
                  23 | 12/12/2016   | 12/20/2016 |       113 |             112 
                  23 | 12/13/2016   | 12/20/2016 |       113 |             112
```

I tried like this, but I guess I am missing something in second min clause.

```
SELECT 
  student_id,
  type_of_sub,
  school_start_dt, 
  school_end_dt, 
  case 
    when type_of_sub != min(type_of_sub) OVER (
      PARTITION BY student_id, school_start_dt 
      ORDER by type_of_sub 
      ROWS BETWEEN 1 preceding and 1 preceding
      )
    then 1 
    else 0 
  end as TOB_DIFFERENT, 
  min(type_of_sub) OVER (
    PARTITION BY student_id, school_start_dt 
    ROWS between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
  ) as FIRST_TOB    
FROM students
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first value, use `first_value()`:

```
select s.*,
       first_value(typeofsub) over (partition by student_subscriber order by school_start, school_end) as first_typeofsub
from students s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6f952a9a57ad74e65680e80b7efb3bc3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: :not working for me. Initial 5 rows are for student 22 and first 4 rows have same start date. Therefore it selects the min type_of_sub as 111 for that. But, for the fifth row, it has different start_date. Thats why we need to check if end date of previous rows is same for the current start date. If yes, it should display the type of sub for that. (in this table 5th row has different start date as the others in previous rows for the same student.Therefore we start checking end_date for that. and since the first row has same end_date. We need to consider that type_of_sub in our output.)

Comment: @SQLPractice . . . It is using two columns for the order by, so it works.

Comment: Yes, But School end date is different always and we need to compare current school start with previous school_end. if school_start changes or is not same.

Comment: @SQLPractice . . . Look at the db<>fiddle.  This does exactly what the question is asking for.

Comment: Hi Gordon,Thanks for your help. Yes, it does. But when I add different dates. It won't.Like in your db<>fiddle, I have added 2 more entries for student 22 But still it is displaying first type of bill as 111, which should not be happening.As for the 2 rows entered, admission dates are different. Row 13 entry there has different start date and end date is not related to previous start dates. But still  it is displaying 111 and not 113. For Row 14, start date is diff but start date is same with end date of row 13 and still we are getting 111 as output instead of 113.

Comment: Any help? I am stuck on this from so many days.I need your help :(